# Trigger action when countdown timer is consumed

Tags: org-mode

I would like to start the countdown function, `(org-timer-set-timer)` (`C-c C-x ;`), and trigger an action once the timer is over.
Any hints on how this could be achieved?
Shall I just use the `run-at-time` function instead? (This wouldn't show the countdown timer in the mode bar, but I guess I could survive).

Comment: `org-timer-done-hook`?

Comment: I know nothing about 'hooks', but thanks for the pointer, it looks like it is like a trigger which is what I think I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'hooks' are variables to which you can add functions that will get
automatically called, so that you don't need to go changing the
original source code to get a behaviour change. This particular one is
not documented, apart from its name. You can use it by doing eg:

```
(defun my-org-timer-hook ()
  (message "My timer done"))
(add-hook 'org-timer-done-hook 'my-org-timer-hook)
```

See [(emacs) Hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html#Hooks)
for a fuller explanation.

Comment: `C-h v org-timer-done-hook` says "Hook run after countdown timer reaches zero." so strictly speaking, it *is* documented. Do you mean "documented in the manual"?

Comment: I somehow missed that, even though I was looking at org-timer.el. Documentation in the manual would be nice.

Comment: I doubt that it is going to be documented in the manual: it's a bit too generic, so the general emacs hook documentation that you linked to probably covers it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this... I have extended your solution with an example of playing a sound file with `afplay` on MacOS when org-timer ends:

```
; play sound when org-timer completes
(add-hook 'org-timer-done-hook (lambda () (interactive)
                                 (shell-command "afplay $HOME/Downloads/ShipsBell.wav")))
```

Hope this proves useful for someone on the Internetz